# extract English words from string in python

Tags: python, regex, mapreduce

I have a document that each line is a string. It might contain digits, non-English letters and words, symbols(such as ! and *). I want to extract the English words from each line(English words are separated by space).
My code is the following, which is the map function of my map-reduce job. However, based on the final result, this mapper function only produces letters(such as a,b,c) frequency count. Can anyone help me find the bug? Thanks

```
import sys
import re

for line in sys.stdin:
    line = re.sub("[^A-Za-z]", "", line.strip())
    line = line.lower()
    words = ' '.join(line.split())
    for word in words:
        print '%s\t%s' % (word, 1)
```

Comment: you're rejoining your split line.  So `words` results in a single string.

Comment: Your regex is removing all the spaces between words. A pattern like `"[^A-Za-z\\s]"` will leave the spaces intact (but you might end up with multiple spaces when removing multiple non-word items)

Comment: monkut and Marius,  is there a good solution.  I don't want extra spaces count in my outcome, that is why I tried to split line

Comment: @Jin: Why are you joining them back up? `for word in line.split():` will give you words, because you're iterating over a list of strings; `for word in ' '.join(line.split()):` will give you individual characters, because you're iterating over a string.

Comment: meta to your question, you should investigate a NLP library like `nltk` for whatever it is you are doing

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You've actually got two problems.

First, this:

```
line = re.sub("[^A-Za-z]", "", line.strip())
```

This removes all non-letters from the line. Which means you no longer have any spaces to split on, and therefore no way to separate it into words.

Next, even if you didn't do that, you do this:

```
words = ' '.join(line.split())
```

This doesn't give you a list of words, this gives you a single string, with all those words concatenated back together. (Basically, the original line with all runs of whitespace converted into a single space.)

So, in the next line, when you do this:

```
for word in words:
```

You're iterating over a string, which means each `word` is a single character. Because that's what strings are: iterables of characters.

If you want each word (as your variable names imply), you already had those, the problem is that you joined them back into a string. Just don't do this:

```
words = line.split()
for word in words:
```

Or, if you want to strip out things besides letters and whitespace, use a regular expression that strips out everything besides letters and whitespace, not one that strips out everything besides letters, including whitespace:

```
line = re.sub(r"[^A-Za-z\s]", "", line.strip())
words = line.split()
for word in words:
```

However, that pattern is still probably not what you want. Do you really want to turn `'abc1def'` into the single string `'abcdef'`, or into the two strings `'abc'` and `'def'`? You probably want either this:

```
line = re.sub(r"[^A-Za-z]", " ", line.strip())
words = line.split()
for word in words:
```

… or just:

```
words = re.split(r"[^A-Za-z]", line.strip())
for word in words:
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues here:

1. `line = re.sub("[^A-Za-z]", "", line.strip())` will remove all the non-characters, making it hard to split word in the subsequent stage. One alternatively solution is like this `words = re.findall('[A-Za-z]', line)`
2. As mentioned by @abarnert, in the existing code `words` is a string, `for word in words` will iterate each letter. To get `words` as a list of words, you can follow 1.